# How to restrict users from creating a model that they don't have access to

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have **Workspace** and **Request** models. A **Workspace** can have multiple **Users** assigned to it. Any **User** can create a request. I want to restrict a user from creating a request on only those **Workspaces** that he/she has access to.

Currently, in my **create** method, I am explicitly checking if the user is assigned to the workspace as shown in the code attached. But I am curious to know if I can use django permissions to do this in a better way. I have attempted to implement the **get_permissions** method as shown in the code.

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Workspace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('creation_date', auto_now_add=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Workspace: %r, %r, %r>' % (self.id, self.name, self.users)


class Request(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='NEW')
    status_msg = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    query_str = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    request_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='AD')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('creation_date', auto_now_add=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Request %r, %r, %r, %r>' % (self.id, self.query_str, self.status, self.status_msg)

# views.py
class RequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            workspace_id = request.data['workspace']
            # check if user has access to this workspace
            if Workspace.objects.filter(pk=workspace_id).filter(users=request.user.id).exists():
                print('workspace exists')
                request.data['user'] = request.user.id
                print(request.data)
                return super(RequestViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)


    def get_permissions(self):
            """
            Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
            """
            print(self.action)
            if self.action == 'create':
                permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
            else:
                permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
            print(permission_classes)
            return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to apply is object-level permission. you do not need to use django permissions to do that. Instead, you can do that by getting use of `request.user`, which holds the current user making that request. So you will need something like:

```py
def your_view(request, pk):
    workspace = models.Workspace.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.user not in workspace.users.all():
        # user is not related to that workspace, permission denied
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        # permission granted, do what you want
        pass
```

Instead of raising an exception, you can change your behavior when user has no permission such as returning a 403 html template etc. It depends on your design.